# Use Regex for make sure a space after an '&'?

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I'm trying to come up with the best way to detect if the user entered a '&' in a text field, and to make sure there is a space after it.

For example, if a user enters:

```
  Apples & Oranges
```

All works out fine. However, if they enter:

```
 Apples &Oranges
```

They get an alert. Or if they have:

```
 Apples&Oranges
```

Same thing.

What would be the best way to make sure that if the user enters an '&', they have a space after it?

Here is the code I have so far:

```
 function entityKiller() {
var good = true;

 $('input[type=text]:visible').each( function() {
        if(/----Regex Here-----/.test($(this).val())) {
            good = false;
            return;
        }
});

return good;
```

}

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: And how do you think it should be?

Comment: @streetlight: the answers below suggest using `\s` which is any whitespace, and not the same as a space character.  Be careful.  If the user inserts a tab or a newline after the ampersand, their regex would also work - I'm not sure if this is a problem for you.  In any case if you only want to check for space after the ampersand the best way would be `&\ `

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try to find `&` followed by a non-space character. If then invert the output of `test`:

```
if(!(/&\S/.test($(this).val()))) {
    ...
}
```

What if your pattern ends with `&`? In that case there is no space after the `&`. However, my above example would consider it valid. If it shouldn't then you need to find a `&` that is not followed by a space (instead of one that is followed by a non-space):

```
if(!(/&(?!\s)/.test($(this).val()))) {
    ...
}
```

Ugly, ugly, multiple negation.

**EDIT:**

As Anton points out, this assumes you want to allow for any kind of whitespace after `&`. If you really just want space characters, the patterns become:

```
/&[^ ]/
```

and

```
/&(?![ ])/
```

**EDIT 2:**

By the way, if you really want to avoid using negative logic, you will have to check that every `&` in your string is followed by a space. That is this pattern:

```
/^[^&]*(?:&[ ][^&]*)$/
```

Where the anchors `^` and `$` make sure that the entire string is matched by the pattern.

Comment: Don't use \s unless you want to match spaces, tabs and line breaks too (that's what it does).

Comment: @Anton yeah sure... sorry, interpreted the question as being interested in whitespace

Answer (score 0):

Try this regex & followed by not a space

```
/&[^\s]/
```

Answer (score 0):

If there is not an `&` or there *is an `&` and it is followed by [space]* return `"success"`.

```
if( $(this).val().match(/(&\s)?/g) ) { /* ok */ }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way is to check whether there are ampersands without spaces, and add them automatically when the data is submitted. Giving the user a warning for something like this is, in my opinion, a little bit of a hassle.

Either way, use this RegEx to match instances of the ampersand being either followed by or preceded by a character that is not a space:

```
/(&[^ ]+)|([^ ]+&)/
```

You can deal with the code to add the space from here.

Note: I'm not using **\s** because it matches on spaces, tabs and line breaks too, and in your question you're asking for spaces only.

Answer (score 0):

```
[a-zA-Z]*\\s&\\s[A-Za-z]*
    |      |        |
  anytext  |        |
           |        anytext
          Space
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
/&[^\w]/
```

It would allow & followed by any whitespace character. Replace \w with a space if that's what you need. Test it here: http://jsfiddle.net/X7c6T/

Answer (score 0):

you can try with this: **http://jsfiddle.net/L2yr2/**

```
$('input[type="text"]').keydown(function() {
    var regex = /[^a-z*]+&+[ ]+[a-z*]/;
    if (regex.test($('input[type="text"]').val())) {
       $('span').text('good match');
    } else {
       $('span').text('not matched');
    }
});
```